# Server can't examine the string sent to it from a client

Tags: c, string, client

Story : Server is suppose to print "`bbb`", if it receives the message "`aaa`" from the client.

Problem : It is not printing "`bbb`"
Suspicion : Perhaps `Their_Message` does not equate to "`aaa`". 
Question : What should be done in a situation like this ?

Update : The way client sends a message perhaps contains a new line.

```
echo "aaa" | nc localhost 90
```

Problematic portion of the code:

```
for (;;) {
    Me_and_Them = accept(Path_to_Me,
                         (struct sockaddr *) &Their_Address,
                         &sin_len);

    char Their_Message[50];

    size_t Bytes_To_Read;
    Bytes_To_Read = sizeof(Their_Message);

    ssize_t Bytes_Read;
    Bytes_Read = read(Me_and_Them, Their_Message, Bytes_To_Read);

    Their_Message[Bytes_Read] = 0;

    if (strcmp(Their_Message, "aaa") == 0) {
        fputs("bbb\n", stdout);
    }

    write(Me_and_Them, "test\n", strlen("test\n"));
    close(Me_and_Them);
}
```

Comment: what's in `Their_Message` after the call to `read` returns?

Comment: @yano, I placed `fputs(Their_Message, stdout);` right under the `read()` and the output is : `aaa`, but perhaps it contains a new line.

Comment: Does the client append a newline? If so, you've answered your own question.

Comment: It very well could. To find out for sure you can examine the memory in a debugger or print out the byte values in the buffer. Or you can simply terminate the string with `Their_Message[3] = 0;` if you're always expecting a string length of 3.

Comment: There are lots of ways you can figure this out yourself. Perhaps the best way is to use the debugger and step through it line-by-line. Also, add a bunch of `printf` statements (ex `printf("Bytes_Read = %d\n", Bytes_Read);`. Also you should check the return values of the functions. For example, `accept` can return `-1` on error.

Comment: @yano, Thank you for all the information. `Their_Message[3] = 0;` will probably be very useful to me.